# Hiding quick response options after using them once in a Dialogflow-Kommunicate chatbot

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx, kommunicate

I am implementing a chatbot with **Dialogflow** and have used **Kommunicate** to integrate it to a website. I want to hide/ disable quick responses after they are once used. How can I do it?

An example of how quick responses are displayed in my bot is given here: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIVtd.png)

Answer (score 3):

Kommunicate provides a parameter named `hidePostCTA`, you need to pass that as `true` in your installation script, with this, rich message buttons will get hidden on click. Please refer documentation for more info [ [documentation link](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/web-customization#hide-rich-message-buttons-on-click) ].

So your final installation script should look something like

```js
(function(d, m){
    var kommunicateSettings = {
        "appId": "APP_ID",
        "popupWidget": true,
        "automaticChatOpenOnNavigation": true,
        "hidePostCTA": true,
    };
    var s = document.createElement("script"); s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true;
    s.src = "https://widget.kommunicate.io/v2/kommunicate.app";
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; h.appendChild(s);
    window.kommunicate = m; m._globals = kommunicateSettings;
})(document, window.kommunicate || {});
```